# How to avoid security issue when I try to show a RDLC report in pop-up window?

Tags: asp.net, .net, report, rdlc

As the title, I try to show the RDLC reports in a pop-up window. But the Chart type report could not be showed instead of with a "no image found" picture, while the table type report could be showed correctly. 
And I also try just show the report in the parent page, then it works fine. I think it brought by the security setting of browsers. 
How to avoiding this issue? As I do not want every user to change their setting when they run the report...

Comment: This may be related to the stupid security warning that exists in IE whereby any url accessed via HTTPS that has references to images whose URL is HTTP and not HTTPS, displays a security warning that the user must acknowledge before rendering the image.

Comment: I have fixed this issue. The reason that issue occur is because the missing configuration in web.config.